# youtube player iframe embed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Im using youtube embed api to add video to my site https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

```
var player = new YT.Player(playerEl, {
            width: "450",
            height: "250",
            controls : 0,
            showinfo : 0,
            videoId: videoId,
        });
```

The problem is that I dont want to show video Info and controls on my video... but i just cannot get this working. Is there a way to remove info nad controls for iframe embed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var player = new YT.Player(playerEl, {
        width: "450",
        height: "250",
        videoId: videoId,
        playerVars: {
        controls: "0",
        showinfo: "0"
        }
    });
```